# What's the meaning of System.out.println in Java?

Tags: java, system.out

Is this static `println` function in `out` class from `System` namespace?

```
namespace System {
  class out {
    static println ...
  }
```

How can I interpret this name? And where in JRE this function is defined? In `java.lang.System`/`java.lang.Object`?

Comment: JDK is open source. Pick an IDE, include the JDK source and Ctrl+Click your way through the `System.out` :)

Comment: @prosseek, i will suggest you to use netbeans, and just type System.out.println(); on it and place mouse cursor over System and press control key and mouse left click too, you will get the definition of System class and then everything will be cleared to you... :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

No. Actually `out` is a static member in the `System` class (not as in .NET), being an instance of `PrintStream`. And `println` is a normal (overloaded) method of the `PrintStream` class.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out.

Actually, if `out`/`err`/`in` were classes, they would be named with capital character (`Out`/`Err`/`In`) due to the [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) (ignoring grammar).

Comment: +1 for referencing Java naming convention as questioner is coming from other language(s).

Comment: Also note that System.java is slightly misleading as in,out and err are set by "magic".

Comment: @Dimitris: Hehe because that's the first hit from Google. Updated to SE 6.

Comment: What is meant by "not as in .NET"?

Comment: @Fabian: The .net BCL has a `System` namespace. If we ignore naming conventions for a second, `System.out` may well be a class named `out` in the `System` namespace, as the OP was first thinking. That's not how it is in Java.

Answer (score 48):

`System` is a class, that has a public static field `out`.  So it's more like

```
class System 
{
    public static PrintStream out;
}

class PrintStream
{
    public void println ...
}
```

This is a slight oversimplification, as the `PrintStream` class is actually in the `java.io` package, but it's good enough to show the relationship of stuff.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati: That'd be outside the scope of this question and answer.  You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 28):

> **System.out.println()**

**High level Understanding**

For understanding this we need to recall few basics of java:

- dot (.) operator in java: In java . (dot operator) is used only to call methods or variables.
  So we can say out is either method or variable.
- Methods in java : we know methods always have parenthesis ‘( )’ after method name, So out cannot be a method in java. **So out its a variable and println() is a method**.
- Class name in java: Class name should start with Capital letter ideally in java, **So System is a class**.

Now with basic knowledge of java we know :

- System is a Class
- out is a Variable
- println() is a method

**Lets get more in details:**

**out variable**: static or instance?

- called using class name, so we know its static variable of System class.
- but its calling a method println() method so ‘out’ is an object of the reference type PrintStream.

the System class belongs to java.lang package

```
class System {
  public static final PrintStream out;
  //...
}
```

the Prinstream class belongs to java.io package

```
class PrintStream{
public void println();
//...
}
```

Explained answer on my youtube what is [System.out.println](https://youtu.be/tFDxh3BHmm4)

Comment: Best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Check following link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

You will clearly see that:

`System` is a **class** in the `java.lang` package.

`out` is a **static member** of the `System` class, and is an instance of `java.io.PrintStream`.

`println` is a **method** of `java.io.PrintStream`.  This method is overloaded to print message to output destination, which is typically a console or file.

Answer (score 7):

`println` and `print` are the two overloaded methods which belong to the [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class.

To access them we need an instance of this class.

A **static property** called `out` of type `PrintStream` is created on the [`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class.

Hence to access the above methods we use the following statements:

```
System.out.println("foo");
System.out.print("foo");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

1. **`System`**: It is the name of standard class that contains objects
   that encapsulates the standard **I/O** devices of your system.

It is contained in the **package** `java.lang`. Since `java.lang` package is imported in every java program by default,therefore **`java.lang` package** is the only package in Java API which does not require an import declaration.

2. **`out`:**The object out represents output stream(i.e Command
   window)and is the static data member of the class
   **`System`**.

So note here **`System.out`** (*`System` -Class   &  `out`- static object i.e why its simply referred to by classname and we need not create any object*).

3. **`println`:**The `println()` is **method**  of `out` object that
   takes the text string as an argument and displays it to the standard
   output i.e *on monitor screen*.

*Note*
**`System`   -Class**
**`out`      -static Object**
**`println()` -method**
 
  *Remember a function (in java function is called method) always  has the format **function()***

Answer (score 2):

•   `System` is a class in `java.lang` package

•   `out` is a `static` object of `PrintStream` class in `java.io` package

•   `println()` is a method in the `PrintStream` class

Answer (score 2):

`System` is a class of `java.lang` package, `out` is an object of `PrintStream` class and also `static` data member of `System` class, `print()` and `println()` is an instance method of `PrintStream` class.
it is provide soft output on console.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple to understand the question, but to answer it we need to dig deeper in to Java native code.

- `System` is static class and cannot be instantiated
- `out` is a reference variable defined in `System`
- `println()` is the method used to print on standard output.

A [brief and nice explanation](http://www.javastudychannel.com/forum/2114-What-out-System.out.println-Java.aspx) is always welcome on this as we can learn much from this single line of statement itself!

Answer (score 1):

Because out is being called with the `System` class name itself, not an instance of a class (an object), So `out` must be a static variable belonging to the class `System`. `out` must be instance of a class, because it is invoking the method `println()`.

```
// the System class belongs to java.lang package
class System {
    public static final PrintStream out;
}
class PrintStream {
    public void println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System` is a class in `java.lang package`. And `out` is a `PrintStream` object. Nice explanation @ http://lazy-geeks.blogspot.in/2015/01/what-is-systemoutprintln.html

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println();
```

[`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is the class

[`out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a variable in the `System` class and it is a `static` and variable type is [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Here is the `out` variable in `System` class:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

You can see implementation of [`System` here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java).

`println()` is a overloaded method in `PrintStream` class.

`PrintStream` includes three overloaded printing methods, those are:

1. `print()`
2. `println()`
3. `printf()`

You can see [implementation of `PrintStream` here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/io/PrintStream.java).

You cannot instantiate `System` class and it is child class of `Object` and the `Object` is the father(superclass) of every classes including classes that you defined.

Here is what the oracle docs says:

> `public final class System extends Object`
>
> The `System` class contains several useful class fields and methods. It
>   cannot be instantiated.
>
> Among the facilities provided by the `System` class are standard input,
>   standard output, and error output streams; access to externally
>   defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files
>   and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of
>   an array.
>
> Since:
>       JDK1.0

If you donot know [what is meant by instantiate, read this questioh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290879/meanings-of-declaring-instantiating-initializing-and-assigning-an-object). It is C# question but the concept is same.

Also, [What is the difference between an Instance and an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885385/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-an-object)

If you donot know [what is meant by overload read this quesiotn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123180/what-is-overloading-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

`System` is a class in `java.lang` package.

`out` is the static data member in `System` class and reference variable of `PrintStream` class.

`Println()` is a normal (overloaded) method of `PrintStream` class.

Comment: I think you mean overridden, not overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println
```

`System` is a class in the `java.lang` package.

`out` is a `static` data member of the `System` class and references a variable of the `PrintStream` class.

Answer (score 0):

**`System`:** is predefined class of `java.lang` package.

**`out`:** is a `static` member of `printStream` class and its connect with console.

**`Println`:** is a method of `printstream` class and its not a `static`.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc about `System`, here's what the doc says:

```
public final class System
extends Object

The System class contains several useful class fields and methods. It cannot be instantiated.
Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input, standard output, and error output streams; access to externally defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of an array.

Since:
JDK1.0
```

Regarding `System.out`

```
public static final PrintStream out

The "standard" output stream class Prinstream  belongs to java.io package. This stream is already open and ready to accept output data. 
When the JVM is initialized, the method initializeSystemClass() is called that does exactly what it’s name says – it initializes the System class and sets the out variable. The initializeSystemClass() method actually calls another method to set the out variable – this method is called setOut().
Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user.
```

Regarding println();

```
class PrintStream{
public void println();
}
```

For simple stand-alone Java applications, a typical way to write a line of output data is:

```
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**System** is the java class.

**out** is the instance and also static member of PrintStream.

**println** is the method of PrintStream.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("...") in Java code is translated into JVM. Looking into the JVM gave me better understanding what is going on behind the hood.

From the book [Programming form the Java Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309726).
This code is copied from https://github.com/ymasory/programming-for-the-jvm/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld.j.

This is the JVM source code.

```
.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 2
.limit locals 1
  getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ldc "Hello, world"
  invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println
    (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  return

.end method
.end class
```

As "The JVM doesn't permit byte-level access to memory" the `out` object in type L`java/io/PrintSteram`; is stored in a stack with `getstatic` JVM command. 
Then the argument is pushed on the stack before called a method `println` of the `java/io/PrintStream` class from an instance named `out`. The method's parameter is (L`java/lang/String`;) and output type is void (V).

Answer (score -1):

`System` - class which is `final` in nature. `public final class System{}`. Belongs to `java.lang` package

`out` - `static` reference variable of type `PrintStream`

`println()` - non `static` method in `PrintStream` class.
`PrintStream` belongs to `java.io` package.

To understand it better you can visit : [How System.out.println() Works In Java](http://tutorialscrux.com/java/systemoutprintln/system-out-println-java-explained/)

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow! This question already has a broadly accepted answer. While it is okay to post answers on old questions, make sure it has a high relevance and that it contributes something new. Also, please keep in mind that posting links to external websites is discouraged because the link can get outdated. Happy coding!