# What is the Exact Meaning of the "System.out.println()" in java

Tags: java

Can any one explain exactly what the below means::

```
System.out.println()
```

I know that :

System : Is a class

**I don't know about "out"**

`println`  : Static Method.

Comment: See the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 11):

`out` is a static field that holds a reference to `PrintStream` object.

`println` is NOT a static method.

Here is the declaration of the `out` variable in `System.java`

```
/**
 * The "standard" output stream. This stream is already
 * open and ready to accept output data. Typically this stream
 * corresponds to display output or another output destination
 * specified by the host environment or user.
 * <p>
 * For simple stand-alone Java applications, a typical way to write
 * a line of output data is:
 * <blockquote><pre>
 *     System.out.println(data)
 * </pre></blockquote>
 * <p>
 * See the <code>println</code> methods in class <code>PrintStream</code>.
 *
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println()
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(boolean)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(char)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(char[])
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(double)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(float)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(int)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(long)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.Object)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String)
 */
public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream();
```

And this is how `println` method looks like:

```
/**
 * Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string.  The
 * line separator string is defined by the system property
 * <code>line.separator</code>, and is not necessarily a single newline
 * character (<code>'\n'</code>).
 */
public void println() {
newLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

out is a static field of System, of class PrintStream:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 2):

"out" is a static public field with Stream value.

```
public final class System {
    public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream();
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`out` is a class static field of type `PrintStream`. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Answer (score 2):

`System` is a class. `out` is a static field of the `System` class, and its type is `PrintStream`. `println` is an instance method of the `PrintStream` class.

Just look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), and you'll have all the info you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Source Page](http://www.chetanasforum.com/index.php?showtopic=463)

`System.out.println()`

`System` is a built-in class present in the `java.lang` package.
This class has a final modifier, which means that, it cannot be inherited by other classes.
It contains predefined methods and fields, which provides facilities like standard input, output, etc.

`out` is a static final field (ie, variable) in the System class, which is of the type `PrintStream` (a built-in class, contains methods to print the different data values).
static fields and methods must be accessed by using the class name, so ( `System.out` ).

`out` here denotes the reference variable of the type `PrintStream` class.

`println()` is a public method in the `PrintStream` class used to print the data values.
Hence to access a method in the PrintStream class, we use `out.println()` (as non static methods and fields can only be accessed by using the reference variable)

eg:

```
int i = 3;
System.out.println(i);
```

The above code prints the value of 3 in the screen and brings the control to the next line.

Comment: [Similar question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406703/whats-the-meaning-of-system-out-println-in-java/11202369#11202369),

[Similar question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004856/just-wondering-system-out-println/11202355#11202355)

Answer (score 0):

Q. To find the length of S in given code, what you have to write in place of    Ans??

```
 class Test{

       static String S="java";

       public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println(Ans);

       }

 }

 Ans: Test.S.length()
```

1. Here, S is static variable of type String present in Test class
2. So, static variable is access using class_name.static_variable_name as Test.S
3. To find length of static variable S, length() method is used of class String where S is an object and we know object can access method as S.length()

Same concept is used in **System.out.println()** as:

```
 class System{

      static PrintStream out;

 }
```

1. System is class_name
2. out is static variable of type PrintStream present in System class. It is also an object of class PrintStream and access method println() of same class.