# Just wondering System.out.println()

Tags: java

Just asking if I have the right understanding

```
System.out.println();
```

System is the package
out is the class
println() is the method

If this is wrong, then please tell me what the correct answer is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No,

- **`System`** is the class, which resides in `java.lang` package (that's why you don't need to import it).
- **`out`** is a static variable of `System` class. It is *public*, so that you can access it from outside and it is *static* so that you it's associated to the class declaration and not to any instance of it.
- **`println()`** is a method, indeed. And it is a method of `out` variable, which is a `PrintStream` instance.

Comment: so PrintStream is the Class and out is the static instance of that class??

Comment: no, `System` is the class, `out` is a static instance of a `PrintWriter` class. This instance is contained in `System` but since it's static it belongs to the `System` namespace itself and not to any instance of `System`.

Comment: ok I get that. Another question in java.lang.package.. is package here  is the library?? because in java.lang.math.. math is the library.

Comment: Java doesn't make a distinction between "package" and "library."  If you mean `java.lang.Math`, `Math` is a class.

Answer (score 1):

out is a static object of [printstream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) class
`System -class,`

`PrintStream -class`,

`out - static object of PrintStream class` ,

`println - public method in PrintStream Class`

Answer (score 1):

```
System = class
out = static object of the PrintStream class
println() = method
```

read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 1):

`System` is not a package. It is a `class` which is contained inside `java.lang` package

Take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

`out` is a `PrintStream` object (`static` in case of `System` class) in which `println()` is one of the methods

Comment: `System` is NOT an object.  It is a class that is designed to never be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

`System` is a class from package java.lang. 
`out` is a public, static member of `System` class, and `println` is a method, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, your understanding is wrong.

"Then What is right" -

`System` - a class,

`out` - a static public member of type `PrintStream` ,

and oh yes `println()` is a method.

You were 33% right ;) [read java documentation for this here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)