# What is a relationship between System class and PrintStream Class

Tags: java, system.out

I'm trying to know what exactly System.out.println(). I read these two articles
[What is System, out, println in System.out.println() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002170/what-is-system-out-println-in-system-out-println-in-java) and [What's the meaning of System.out.println in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406703/whats-the-meaning-of-system-out-println-in-java). I know what is System,out,and print, But i don't know how System class can connect to `PrintStream class`. How they are `related to each other`?

System is a class in the `java.lang package.out` is a static member of the System class, So how its becomes an instance of `java.io.PrintStream` ?How System and PrintStream are related to each other ?

Comment: The class `System` has a field which is of type `PrintStream`. See the "Field Summary" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html.

Answer (score 3):

The relation between System class and PrintStream class is HAS-A relation.
Here System class HAS-A PrintStream class.
To understand the relation understand the program.

```
class A
{    
    void display()
    {   
        System.out.pritln("this is display method");
    }

}

class B

{
    static A ob=new A();
}

class demo
{
    public static void main()
    {
    B.ob.display();
    }
}
```

It prints this is display method.

B.ob.display() is just like System.out.println().

A object is created in B class.

PrintStream class object is created in System class.

ob is static object reference of A class.

out also static reference of PrintStream class.

Answer (score 1):

`System` class has static object of `PrintStream` class which is declared in `System` class as `out` and the `println()` is the method of `PrintStream` class.

So we can access static object as `System.out` and the `println()` is the method of `PrintStream` class. That's why we can write `System.out.println()` and how both classes are related.