# Explanation to a certain java command

Tags: java, class, printing, this

```
System.out.println(((Window)this).size);
```

Say we have a class Window and the above command is written inside a method in a subclass. I want some help understanding what (Window)this does exactly. Where it refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose both the sub-class and the `Window` class have a member called class. In this case, the sub-class's `size` hides `Window`'s `size`.

`((Window)this).size` returns the `size` member of the `Window` class (assuming it's accssible), while `this.size` will return the `size` member of the sub-class.

Comment: So if we say that Window is the superclass writing ((Window)this).size and super.size is the same thing?

Comment: @ohyez96 Yes, both would return the same value

Answer (score 0):

> System.out.println(((Window)this).size);

Can be broken down in steps as:

- `this` A reference to the current instance
- `(Window)this` cast as the `Window` class so non private `Window` members are accessible
- `(Window)this.size` Access the size member of this Window
- `System.out` refers to the reference variable of the type PrintStream class
- `System` [Statically refers to a final class from java.lang package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002271/1493294)
- `out` a reference to the PrintStream class and a static member of System class
- `println` is a method of PrintStream class

Altogether,

```
System.out.println(((Window)this).size);
```

will send this windows size to the console (provided `out` hasn't been redirected) and follow it with a new line.