# Stopwatch - System class in java

Tags: java

Could you please tell me, what is the "`System.` " in this code?
and why they used it?
when we should use "`System.` "?
Where can I know I should use `System.` for `nanoTime()`?

```
 // A class to measure time elapsed.   
  public class Stopwatch{
    private long startTime;
    private long stopTime;

    public static final double NANOS_PER_SEC = 1000000000.0;

     // start the stop watch.
    public void start(){
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    // stop the stop watch.
    public void stop()
    {   stopTime = System.nanoTime();   }


    // elapsed time in seconds.
    // @return the time recorded on the stopwatch in seconds
    public double time()
    {   return (stopTime - startTime) / NANOS_PER_SEC;  }

    public String toString(){
        return "elapsed time: " + time() + " seconds.";
    }

    // elapsed time in nanoseconds.
    // @return the time recorded on the stopwatch in nanoseconds
    public long timeInNanoseconds()
    {   return (stopTime - startTime);  }
}
```

Comment: just google of system in java or pick a beginner book from shelf to know what is system. If after that code is not working properly then only ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the [`java.lang.System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class. (The `java.lang` package is imported automatically.)

`nanotime()` is a static method within `System`, and `out` is a static field in `System` - so it's just making use of those members.

If you're not sure what static methods and fields are, you might want to read the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 2):

> System.out.println()

**System** is a class in `java.lang` package,
static fields and methods must be accessed by using the class name, so ( `System.out` ).

**out** here denotes the reference variable of the type `PrintStream` class.

**println()** is a public method in PrintStream class to print the data values.

Since **nanoTime()** is [static](http://crunchify.com/java-static-methods-variables-static-block-and-class-with-example/) method of `System` class you can call it directly with `System.`

[Source1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html),[Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002170/what-is-system-out-println-in-system-out-println-in-java)