# why an array reference variable cant hold address for char array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print the address of the char array. When I try to do it I am getting a string output as "ABC" instead of getting address of the char array.

```
class P
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        char [] ch = {'A','B','C'};
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there is an override specifically to do that for a char array: [`println(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(char[]))

Comment: will you please explain it in depth as i am a beginner and want to know in detail.

Comment: the explaination is right on the link from khelwood's comment

Comment: I suggest learning what [overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123180/what-is-overloading-in-java) is and have a look at the javadoc of the method you just invoked: [println\(char\[\]\)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[]))

Comment: The output of the  `toString` method never gives the "address" of the object. What you are probably referring to as the address is the hashCode.

Comment: I suspect you are one of the few people ever who actually *wants* the nonsensical output of calling `toString()` on an array :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most objects, if you pass them to `println`, you get the normal `toString()` representation of the object. For arrays, it looks something like `[C@6d4b1c02`.

However, there is [a version of `println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(char%5B%5D)) written specifically to accept a `char` array. So if you call that, you don't get the `toString()` representation of the array; you get the contents of the array, in this case `ABC`.

If you were to call the ordinary (non-char[]) version of `println`

```
System.out.println((Object) ch);
```

you would get the impenetrable `[C@6d4b1c02` output.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into `println(char[] ch)` implementation for `char[]` it finally calls below method

```
 public void write(char cbuf[]) throws IOException {
        write(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length);
    }
```

This method write array element from `0` to array length that why you are getting `ABC`.

If you want hash code kind of value you can change your method

```
 System.out.println(ch.toString());
```