# How exactly the line is getting printed on "Console" using System.out.print()

Tags: java

If i want to print a line

> This is Java programming language

to the console using `System.out.print()`, which and how many process gets used to print this line, and how we can compare it with writing the same line to file using `FileWriter` or `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by "how can we compare it"?

Comment: `System.out` is a static final field of type `PrintWriter`. So you're actually using a `PrintWriter`, which works exactly the same as other writers. It's just pre-set to print to the processes standard output.

Comment: This should help http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of System.out.println in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406703/whats-the-meaning-of-system-out-println-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Check PrintStream.java file to know the process of **print** method.

[Check here for detailed flow of process](http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/)

Comment: i am also curious with the reason by the downvoter , please give your reason

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. However, it would be nice to provide a link to it, and even more awesome with part of the code pasted here. For an over-the-top awesome answer, you could add explanations to the code too...

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, but also why upvoted when other answers or even comments give more explanations and have no upvotes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: If "luckytoilet" decides to remove his WordPress site, this answer would be rendered useless. I agree with @AndrewWhitaker.

Answer (score 1):

`out` is a static member of class `System` having type `PrintStream` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html. You can create `PrintStream` objects for files and use them similarly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Answer (score 0):

Different implementations of Java may have different ways of doing the thing in question. You can check out their source if you're interested in how it's being done.

For example in `HotSpot` VM, `out` is a `java.io.PrintStream` reference which internally uses a `java.io.BufferedWriter` to write to the standard output.

Comment: @Lutz Horn ..i want to ask if i print above line 10000 times on console then it will take more time than writing this line 10000 times in file using FileWriter or BufferedWriter.Why and what is reason behind it?

Comment: @DevenPatil - 0) that is not what you asked, 1) test it yourself, and 2) look at the source code.