# Error printing from user input

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a simple JAVA program that I have written in Eclipse and I am using as a building block for a larger program, for some reason, I am getting an error with the ***System.out.println***.

Thanks in advance!

**Error:** The method println(String) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

**Code:**

```
package UserInfo;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class UserInfo {

    public UserInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println ("This program will gather your personal information. \n\n");

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstName = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter your last name: ");
        String lastName = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter your street address: ");
        String addressStreet = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter your city: ");
        String addressCity = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter your two letter state abbreviation (ex:TN): ");
        String addressState = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter your 5 digit zip code: ");
        Integer addressZip = userInput.nextInt();
/*
        System.out.printf ("Enter your phone number (ex: 1234567890): ");
        Integer addressPhone = userInput.nextInt();
*/      
        String addressQualified = (addressStreet + "\n" + addressCity + "" + addressState + ", " + addressZip + "\n");
        String nameQualified = firstName + "" + lastName + "\n";

        System.out.println ("User: ", nameQualified, "\n"); **//Error here**
        System.out.println ("Users Address: ", addressQualified, "\n"); **//Error here**
        //System.out.printf ("User Phone: ", addressPhone, "\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: That is not the correct format for System.out.println(). println() accepts a String argument. You have provided three String arguments. Try doing this: System.out.println ("User: " + nameQualified + "\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 System.out.println ("User: " + nameQualified + "\n"); **//Error here**
 System.out.println ("Users Address: " + addressQualified + "\n"); **//Error here**
```

Wrong syntax, it's "+" instead of ","

"+" is used for concatenation of String

"," is used to separate different arguments/parameters for methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just as it says, there is no method for `System.out.println` with three String parameters. You probably meant to do this:

```
System.out.println ("User: " + nameQualified + "\n");
System.out.println ("Users Address: " + addressQualified + "\n");
//System.out.printf ("User Phone: " + addressPhone + "\n");
```

Just so you know, parameters (also called arguments) are separated by commas in method calls. You can see that's why you were actually giving the method three parameters.

The `+` concats strings together, like you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println ("User: ", nameQualified, "\n"); **//Error here**
```

As the error says, println takes only 1 input/arg/param. So concat the input to 1 string as follows:

```
System.out.println ("User: " + nameQualified + "\n");
```

More info here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)

[What's the meaning of System.out.println in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406703/whats-the-meaning-of-system-out-println-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

Wrong syntax, you need to concatenate using the + sign