# Object vs. instance

Tags: oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between an Instance and an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885385/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-an-object)

What is the specific difference between an object and an instance?

Answer (score 4):

An object is an instance of a class.

When you instantiate a class, the result is an object of the class type.

Answer (score 2):

> In short, An object is a software
>   bundle of related state and behavior.
>   A class is a blueprint or prototype
>   from which objects are created. An
>   instance is a single and unique unit
>   of a class.

Read this article: [Class vs Object vs Instance](http://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/)