# Class V.S Object V.S Instance

Tags: java, android, class, object, instance

What is the definition of a Class , Object and an Instance and what is the difference between an Instance and an Object.

**I would like my answer in Simple English**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885385/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-an-object

Answer (score 0):

Class is collection of various objects, variables, functions etc.

```
class DemoClass {

    void method(){
       ......
    }   
}
```

When you want to create a new instance of a class you need to create a new object of that class.

```
DemoClass dc = new DemoClass();
```

You can then access this instance (methods etc. of this instance) from the object you created.

```
dc.method();
```