# What is the instance in Python Classes?

Tags: python, class, oop

I google this question, but unfortunately I can't find answer of this question. If you have an article related to this question, pls share it.

```
class Dog:
    """A simple attempt to model a dog"""
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

my_dog = Dog("Bob",8)
```

What is the instance in this question?

Comment: `my_dog` here is an instance of `Dog`. You can read more about classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Comment: The instance is `my_dog`. Creating an object from a class is called "instanciation", and the resulting object is an instance. It's a OOP-broad term, and googling "instance" is quite enough; have a read at that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances) to understand the difference between class (type) and object/instance (of that type). Like `int` is a type and `1` is an instance of that type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between an Instance and an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885385/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

The Dog named Bob wich is 8 years old is the instance of the Class dog
A Concreat dog wich was Created during the Code execution

my_dog is a Reference/ pointer to the Instance not the instance itself

you can have mutiple variables pointing at the same Instance example

```
my_dog = Dog("Bob", 8)
my_dog2 = my_dog
```

there is only one instance of the Dog named Bob but two pointers

[Mutiple Variables pointing at the same Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYWrV.png)

Comment: Is 8 instance too? or not?

Comment: @FuadFatali both `name` and `age` are attributes/properties of the instance. They have values, in your example `"Bob"` and `8`.

Comment: `8` is a value, integers are value types, not reference types

Answer (score 0):

`my_dog` is the instance here.

Think of class as a model/concept. Eg. A Car is a model which has 4 tyres , has more than 2 seats etc. Say when you actually see car or when an antual car is created , that car will be known as instance of the concept/model.

Answer (score 0):

An individual object of a certain class is called Instance.
In above example **my_dog** is an instance of class Dog.
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

An instance is a concept in object oriented programming, it is not specific of python classes, I think it is quite well explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

> "When you create an object, you are creating an "instance" of a class, therefore "instantiating" a class."

In following line you are instantiating an object of class `Dog` and storing in `my_dog` variable.

```
my_dog = Dog("Bob",8)
```

In your example:

- `Dog` is a **class**
- `my_dog` is a variable where you store an **instance** (or object) of Dog class.
- `name` and `age` are attributes of `Dog` class